# Changing state of a class in Python using a function with @classmethod decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static-methods, class-method

I was reading about the differences in `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` for Python. I know that the `class` as a parameter is passed to the `@classmethod` functions, and not to the `@staticmethod` functions. However, there was a difference stating that **`@classmethod` can be used to change the state of a class.**

What exactly is meant by **state of a class**? There are instance variables, which are specific to objects(instances), and thus determine the **state of the instance**. Then there are class variables (or static variables), which can be accessed and modified by `@staticmethod` functions. However, what does it imply when it is said that **`@classmethod` can change the state of a class?**

Any examples too would be very helpful.

Comment: Anytime you do `MyClass.some_attribute = whatever` you've changed the state of the class, either be mutating an attribute or adding that attribute. The point that I believe this is trying to make is that since a classmethod provides the class as the first argument  you can use the first argument to mutate the class (without having to hard-code the reference to the class, so it can work with *inheritance* for example). So, in *any* method, or anywhere*, you can explicitly do `MyClass.whatever = foo`, but in a classmethod, this is dynamic, `cls.whatever = foo`

Comment: That's what I had thought. However, isn't it that `@staticmethod` can also directly change the `attributes` of class, and hence can change the state of class? This is the part I'm not able to grasp.

Comment: Well, only by hardcoding. But consider you have a `Parent` and `Child` class, and a `staticmethod` `my_method` in `Parent` that does `Parent.foo += 1`, but what if you want `my_method` to modify the state of `Child`? Well, since it is hard-coded, you have to repeat yourself. but if you used a classmethod, it would just work, because it receives an implicit reference to the class (i.e. the class state)

Comment: I should add, `staticmethod` is rarely used in idiomatic Python, in my experience. Honestly, I think it was mostly added to appease Java programmers who insist on putting methods in classes even if those methods don't require internal state, which almost always in Python you can just use a module-level function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga to add to your explanation, I also got the following: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171296/staticmethod-vs-module-level-function?newreg=9cbc153d7cd8463091b9c45364ad0cd0